# Creating Custom Dictionary in Jazzy - java Spell Checker API

Tags: java, dictionary, spell-checking

I am Using Jazzy Spell Checker in my java project with English data.

But current English dictionary couldn't able to check and correct all my spelling errors.

So , i was looking for building custom dictionary.

Please suggest something, how to build custom dictionary in Jazzy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply load as dictionary your words file.
The file must be in plain text (UTF 8 encoding) with one word per line.

Look this link for an [example](http://jazzy.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jazzy/jazzy/src/com/swabunga/spell/examples/SpellCheckExample.java?view=markup)